# validate form php

Tags: php, html

There is a form of a score of several items like:

```
<option value="1"> 1 </option>
<option value="2"> 2 </option>
<option value="3"> 3 </option>
```

The problem is that the value can be changed via firebug ie correcting `value="3"` to `value="30"` - we will have - 30, how to validate form like this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Answer (score 5):

```
   $possible_values = array(1,2,3);
   $val = (int) $_POST['input'];
   if( !in_array( $val, $possible_values)){
     //error
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( in_array( $Int , range( $Min , $Max ) ) )
```

try this